# CKAN 2.5 package: Cannot create organizations, groups

Tags: ckan

In CKAN 2.5 package installation that gets done well, with allowing  users to be created, and the dashboard to be accessed. For some reason, I cannot create organizations and groups (or datasets as a result). The message is "Server error. Internal server error has occurred."

The weird thing is when I visit the organizations and groups pages for the first time, I see the "Add ..." button, and the form opens when clicked. However, when the "Create ..."  is clicked, the server error is shown and remains.

Any help would be appreciated.

The log is below:

```
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:41.697391 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] 2016-06-29 16:53:41,695 ERROR [ckan.lib.search.common] HTTP code=404, reason=Not Found
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:41.697568 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:41.697578 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/search/common.py", line 51, in is_available
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:41.697584 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680]     conn.query("*:*", rows=1)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:41.697591 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 703, in query
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:41.697597 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680]     return self.select(*args, **params)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:41.697603 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 798, in __call__
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:41.697609 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680]     xml = self.raw(**params)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:41.697615 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 823, in raw
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:41.697621 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680]     rsp = conn._post(self.selector, request, conn.form_headers)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:41.697627 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 639, in _post
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:41.697633 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680]     return check_response_status(self.conn.getresponse())
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:41.697640 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 1097, in check_response_status
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:41.697646 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680]     raise ex
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:41.697653 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] SolrException: HTTP code=404, reason=Not Found
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:41.697919 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] 2016-06-29 16:53:41,697 WARNI [ckan.lib.search] Problems were found while connecting to the SOLR server
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:42.223142 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] 2016-06-29 16:53:42,222 ERROR [ckan.lib.search.common] HTTP code=404, reason=Not Found
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:42.223230 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:42.223239 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/search/common.py", line 51, in is_available
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:42.223245 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680]     conn.query("*:*", rows=1)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:42.223286 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 703, in query
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:42.223294 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680]     return self.select(*args, **params)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:42.223299 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 798, in __call__
```

...

```
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:42.223346 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] SolrException: HTTP code=404, reason=Not Found
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:42.223945 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] 2016-06-29 16:53:42,223 WARNI [ckan.lib.search] Problems were found while connecting to the SOLR server
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:42.489981 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] 2016-06-29 16:53:42,489 CRITI [ckan.lib.uploader] Please specify a ckan.storage_path in your config
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:42.490118 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680]                          for your uploads
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:44.006119 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] 2016-06-29 16:53:44,005 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  / render time 1.311 seconds
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.103255 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680] 2016-06-29 16:53:46,102 ERROR [ckan.lib.search.common] HTTP code=404, reason=Not Found
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.103446 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.103455 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/search/common.py", line 51, in is_available
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.103461 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680]     conn.query("*:*", rows=1)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.103466 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 703, in query
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.103472 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680]     return self.select(*args, **params)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.103477 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 798, in __call__
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.103483 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680]     xml = self.raw(**params)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.103488 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 823, in raw
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.103494 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680]     rsp = conn._post(self.selector, request, conn.form_headers)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.103499 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 639, in _post
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.103505 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680]     return check_response_status(self.conn.getresponse())
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.103511 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 1097, in check_response_status
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.103538 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680]     raise ex
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.103544 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680] SolrException: HTTP code=404, reason=Not Found
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.103764 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680] 2016-06-29 16:53:46,103 WARNI [ckan.lib.search] Problems were found while connecting to the SOLR server
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.475674 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680] 2016-06-29 16:53:46,475 ERROR [ckan.lib.search.common] HTTP code=404, reason=Not Found
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.475719 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.475725 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/search/common.py", line 51, in is_available
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.475731 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680]     conn.query("*:*", rows=1)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.475736 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 703, in query
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.475742 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680]     return self.select(*args, **params)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.475747 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 798, in __call__
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.475752 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680]     xml = self.raw(**params)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.475757 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 823, in raw
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.475763 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680]     rsp = conn._post(self.selector, request, conn.form_headers)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.475768 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 639, in _post
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.475773 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680]     return check_response_status(self.conn.getresponse())
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.475779 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 1097, in check_response_status
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.475785 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680]     raise ex
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.475790 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680] SolrException: HTTP code=404, reason=Not Found
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.475990 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680] 2016-06-29 16:53:46,475 WARNI [ckan.lib.search] Problems were found while connecting to the SOLR server
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.725372 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680] 2016-06-29 16:53:46,724 CRITI [ckan.lib.uploader] Please specify a ckan.storage_path in your config
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.725522 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680]                          for your uploads
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:46.973597 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519659431680] 2016-06-29 16:53:46,973 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /api/i18n/en render time 0.030 seconds
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:53.824900 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519541933824] 2016-06-29 16:53:53,824 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /dashboard render time 0.398 seconds
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:54.392203 2016] [:error] [pid 8785:tid 140519558719232] 2016-06-29 16:53:54,391 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /api/i18n/en render time 0.008 seconds
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.471631 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] Error - <class 'ckan.lib.search.common.SearchError'>: SOLR returned an error running query: {'fq': [' +site_id:"default" +state:active'], 'facet.mincount': 1, 'rows': 2, 'facet.field': ['groups', 'owner_org'], 'facet': 'true', 'q': '+capacity:public', 'facet.limit': -1, 'wt': 'json', 'fl': 'groups'} Error: 'Not Found'
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483621 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] URL: http://127.0.0.1/dashboard/organizations
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483657 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/weberror/errormiddleware.py', line 171 in __call__
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483695 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   app_iter = self.application(environ, sr_checker)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483703 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/dec.py', line 147 in __call__
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483709 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   resp = self.call_func(req, *args, **self.kwargs)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483715 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/dec.py', line 208 in call_func
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483721 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   return self.func(req, *args, **kwargs)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483726 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fanstatic/publisher.py', line 234 in __call__
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483732 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   return request.get_response(self.app)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483737 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/request.py', line 1053 in get_response
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483743 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   application, catch_exc_info=False)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483748 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/request.py', line 1022 in call_application
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483754 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   app_iter = application(self.environ, start_response)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483760 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/dec.py', line 147 in __call__
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483765 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   resp = self.call_func(req, *args, **self.kwargs)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483771 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/dec.py', line 208 in call_func
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483776 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   return self.func(req, *args, **kwargs)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483782 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fanstatic/injector.py', line 54 in __call__
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483787 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   response = request.get_response(self.app)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483793 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/request.py', line 1053 in get_response
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483798 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   application, catch_exc_info=False)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483804 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/request.py', line 1022 in call_application
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483809 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   app_iter = application(self.environ, start_response)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483815 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/middleware.py', line 389 in inner
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483820 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   result = application(environ, start_response)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483826 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/beaker/middleware.py', line 73 in __call__
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483839 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   return self.app(environ, start_response)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483846 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/beaker/middleware.py', line 155 in __call__
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483851 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   return self.wrap_app(environ, session_start_response)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483857 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/routes/middleware.py', line 131 in __call__
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483863 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   response = self.app(environ, start_response)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483868 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylons/wsgiapp.py', line 125 in __call__
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483874 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   response = self.dispatch(controller, environ, start_response)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483879 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylons/wsgiapp.py', line 324 in dispatch
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483885 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   return controller(environ, start_response)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483891 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/base.py', line 337 in __call__
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483896 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   res = WSGIController.__call__(self, environ, start_response)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483902 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylons/controllers/core.py', line 221 in __call__
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483907 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   response = self._dispatch_call()
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483913 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylons/controllers/core.py', line 172 in _dispatch_call
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483918 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   response = self._inspect_call(func)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483924 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylons/controllers/core.py', line 107 in _inspect_call
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483930 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   result = self._perform_call(func, args)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483935 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylons/controllers/core.py', line 60 in _perform_call
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483941 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   return func(**args)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483946 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/controllers/user.py', line 665 in dashboard_organizations
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483952 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   return render('user/dashboard_organizations.html')
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483958 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/base.py', line 216 in render
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483963 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   loader_class=loader_class)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483969 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylons/templating.py', line 249 in cached_template
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483981 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   return render_func()
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483987 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/base.py', line 154 in render_template
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483993 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   return render_jinja2(template_name, globs)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.483998 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/base.py', line 104 in render_jinja2
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484004 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   return template.render(**extra_vars)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484009 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py', line 894 in render
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484015 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484021 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/user/dashboard_organizations.html', line 1 in top-level template code
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484027 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   {% extends "user/dashboard.html" %}
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484032 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/user/dashboard.html', line 3 in top-level template code
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484038 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   {% set user = c.userobj %}
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484043 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/user/edit_base.html', line 1 in top-level template code
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484049 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   {% extends "page.html" %}
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484055 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/page.html', line 1 in top-level template code
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484060 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   {% extends "base.html" %}
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484066 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/base.html', line 103 in top-level template code
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484071 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   {%- block page %}{% endblock -%}
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484077 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/page.html', line 19 in block "page"
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484082 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   {%- block content %}
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484088 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/page.html', line 22 in block "content"
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484093 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   {% block main_content %}
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484099 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/page.html', line 57 in block "main_content"
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484104 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   {% block primary %}
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484109 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/user/dashboard.html', line 32 in block "primary"
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484115 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   {% block primary_content_inner %}
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484137 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/user/dashboard_organizations.html', line 13 in block "primary_content_inner"
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484144 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   {% set organizations = h.organizations_available() %}
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484192 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/helpers.py', line 1550 in organizations_available
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484201 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   return logic.get_action('organization_list_for_user')(context, data_dict)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484206 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/logic/__init__.py', line 416 in wrapped
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484212 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   result = _action(context, data_dict, **kw)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484218 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/logic/action/get.py', line 760 in organization_list_for_user
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484224 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   orgs_list = model_dictize.group_list_dictize(orgs_q.all(), context)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484229 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/dictization/model_dictize.py', line 49 in group_list_dictize
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484235 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   group_dictize_context['dataset_counts'] = get_group_dataset_counts()
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484241 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/dictization/model_dictize.py', line 348 in get_group_dataset_counts
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484283 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   query.run(q)
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484289 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/search/query.py', line 364 in run
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484295 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   (query, e.reason))
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484301 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] SearchError: SOLR returned an error running query: {'fq': [' +site_id:"default" +state:active'], 'facet.mincount': 1, 'rows': 2, 'facet.field': ['groups', 'owner_org'], 'facet': 'true', 'q': '+capacity:public', 'facet.limit': -1, 'wt': 'json', 'fl': 'groups'} Error: 'Not Found'
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484308 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] 
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484314 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] 
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484319 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] CGI Variables
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484324 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358] -------------
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484330 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   AUTH_TYPE: 'cookie'
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484335 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   CKAN_CURRENT_URL: '/dashboard/organizations'
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484341 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   CKAN_LANG: 'en'
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484346 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   CKAN_LANG_IS_DEFAULT: True
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484352 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   CONTENT_TYPE: '; charset=utf-8'
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484357 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT: '/var/www'
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484382 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   DOCUMENT_ROOT: '/var/www'
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484389 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   GATEWAY_INTERFACE: 'CGI/1.1'
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484395 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   HTTP_ACCEPT: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484401 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: 'gzip, deflate'
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484406 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: 'en-US,en;q=0.5'
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484412 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   HTTP_CONNECTION: 'close'
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484418 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   HTTP_COOKIE: 'ckan=69cc3ebb1fac1b39f0fa17af0d9bd69581339b250c4c9174e55248eea22d5d913a1af228; auth_tkt="c0a59de758de6aac6cda7a440f92258057737239admin!userid_type:unicode"'
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484424 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   HTTP_HOST: '127.0.0.1'
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484429 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   HTTP_REFERER: 'http://127.0.0.1/dashboard'
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58. 484435 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   HTTP_USER_AGENT: 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0'
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484440 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   PATH_INFO: '/dashboard/organizations'
[Wed Jun 29 16:53:58.484446 2016] [:error] [pid 8784:tid 140519659431680] [remote 127.0.0.1:33358]   PATH_TRANSLATED: '/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi/dashboard/organizations'
```

Same result with setting solr_url = http://127.0.0.1/solr

Comment: The error will be in the log - please provide that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SolrException: HTTP code=404, reason=Not Found
WARNI [ckan.lib.search] Problems were found while connecting to the SOLR server
```

Looks like CKAN can not connect to the Solr server. Make sure this is accessible and that the `solr_url` setting in the ini file points to it.